# php and mysql connection in LAMP

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and i have installed LAMP. While i was learning PHP i came across a topic of connecting mysql and php. This is the code i learn

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','dbpass') or die('Unable to connect. Check your connection ');

$query = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS moviesite';
mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

mysql_select_db('moviesite',$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

$query2 = 'CREATE TABLE movie (movie_id integer not null, moviename varchar(255) not null, movierating integer not null)';

mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

echo "movie database succecfully created ";

?>
```

When i try this in my windows environment (i have dual boot windows and ubuntu) , it works fine. In windows i am using eastPHP. But in ubuntu it doesn't shows anything. I have tried to find syntax errors but its just the same given in a book. So what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a blank page in the browser, you probably have a fatal error or a server configuration issue. Assuming you use Apache, look in the Apache error logs for some clues. On Ubuntu, it would be in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` per default.

Comment: It says   -  :  "[Tue Oct 23 13:50:15 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/dbcon2.php on line 8 "   But isn't my function correct ?

Comment: In that case, you probably need to install the mysql extension. Try with `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`